# Net core 6 + Angular Request request arrives with null properties

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, request

Hi i've a net core 6 project with angular 12.

i've a login controller with his model request.

When I execute the request through swagger or postman it arrives fine, but when I send the request from my angular app all the properties arrive null.

Anyone know what can it be? I have investigated but no case reaches my solution.

my model:

```
public class AuthRequest
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/auth")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly iAuthService _authService;

    public AuthController(iAuthService authService)
    {
        _authService = loginService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Auth(AuthRequest request)
    {
        var response = await _authService.LoginAsync(request);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

request from postman/swagger successful:

[image]

request from angular is bad:

[image]

Angular service:

```
login(payload: AuthModel): Observable<any> {
    //payload = { Username: 'someusername', Password: 'somePassword' }
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}/auth`, payload);
 }
```

Comment: Try define your API like `public async Task<IActionResult> Auth([FromBody]AuthRequest request)`. see the [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this happens when you're sending the data without the proper content type.

Try setting the HTTP client content type and the accept headers, like this.

```
var headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
});

this.http.post(this.oauthUrl, JSON.stringify(postData), {
    headers: headers
})
```